Difference between load factor imposed in a turn vs with wings level

How does the load factor/resultant load in this picture change if instead the pilot is in wings level flight, and yanks back on the yoke enough to produce 1.73Gs of centripetal/centrifugal force? In other words, is the resultant load any different if those 1.73Gs are now acting in the same direction as gravity?

The centrifugal force is the reaction to the centripetal force created by the curved motion. The load factor is the magnitude of the vector sum of centrifugal acceleration and gravity acceleration.
Gravity can be considered constant, centrifugal acceleration is not: Its magnitude varies with the radius of the curve and its direction is normal to the curve.
If you pull-up and fly a circular loop, the centrifugal acceleration is constant in magnitude, but variable in direction. It means the vector sum is not constant. Assuming a centrifugal acceleration of 1.73g:


At the bottom of the circular flight path, both accelerations are colinear, the magnitude of the sum is the sum of the magnitudes: 1+1.73 = 2.73g
At the top, accelerations are also colinear, but now they are in opposite directions, the magnitude of the sum is 1-1.73 = -0.73g
At 90° on each side, accelerations are orthogonal, the situation is the same than in the figure of your question. the magnitude of the sum is 2g.
At other locations the load factor varies with the sine of the angle between the two accelerations.

To fly a loop with a constant load factor, the effect of centrifugal acceleration must be reduced at the bottom of the loop, and increased at the top. The path would be something like:

See also:

What is the definition of load factor and how do you apply it?
Load factor and how does velocity affect it?


Thank you for the answer. Here's a tangent question maybe you could answer. Would the amount of stick force required to pull 1.73 Gs of centrifugal force (2 Gs total load) just as in my picture, be equivalent to the same amount of stick force required to pull 1.73 Gs of centriptal force by yanking back in straight-and-level flight (2.73 Gs. total load) if the airspeeds are exactly the same. What i'm getting at is this: is it actually easier to exceed the limit load factor by yanking back in level flight than it is doing so in a turn? Thanks

It is easier to exceed the max load factor pulling up at high speed (e.g. at the bottom of a curve, in French this is called a "ressource", maybe "recovery" in English, but I'm not sure) than during a turn. The acceleration can be higher and both vectors are in the same direction. You can post another question, I'm sure someone will provide more details.
